# Replacement of Output in Brackets

Tags: replacement, geometry, output

For my programm I have a section where I have to introduce coordinates for my prestressedsteel bars or cords and the associated area in Form of **{{X1,Y1,Area1},{Xi,Yi,Areai}}**.

For my further calculations I need to come back to the Radius which is in relation to the area of the steel. 
In the picture below you can see how I did the replacement of the area with the radius and how I got back to the radius for an Infinity-Number of bars. 
This solutions works but Graphics[] (This Function is used in my programm as well) don't like Transpose[] and my whole programm seems not to work anymore.

**My Question:**

Does someone now how I could replace the area with the radius without using Transpose[] or even without an intermediate step for an unknown amount of bars?

[image: My existing Code]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please post copyable code, not images. People here want to experiment with the code without having to retype it. Moreover,  you should consider to improve your question. I just did not get what your problem is.

Comment: You are right. I'll post the codes for my next question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Prestressedsteel = {{50, 50, 314}, {150, 50, 1018}};
```

Change definition of `v` to

```
v = Round[N[Sqrt[#/Pi]], 0.01] &;
```

Then

```
PrestressedsteelwithRadius =
 {#[[1]], #[[2]], v[#[[3]]]} & /@ Prestressedsteel

(* {{50, 50, 10.}, {150, 50, 18.}} *)
```

Or

```
PrestressedsteelwithRadius =
 ReplacePart[#, 3 -> v[#[[3]]]] & /@ Prestressedsteel

(* {{50, 50, 10.}, {150, 50, 18.}} *)
```

Or

```
PrestressedsteelwithRadius =
 Join[Most[#], {v[Last[#]]}] & /@ Prestressedsteel

(* {{50, 50, 10.}, {150, 50, 18.}} *)
```